# Receiving ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular v16

Tags: angular, ngrx

i created a simple app which uses angular v16 and nrgx.
For a better unterstanding i uploaded an example at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-m8ry8i).

After loading the app and clicking at

> Adresse > Submit > any link

the console raise the error:

> ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'. Expression location: BodyComponent component. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

The Error happens at the files

```js
// body.component.ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listSubscription = this.service
      .getItemModeState()
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.itemMode = result;
        console.log('TEST:', result);
      });
  }
```

```html
// body.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="itemMode >= ItemMode.List"> <a> List</a> > </ng-container>
```

```js
// item.component.ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setItemMode(ItemMode.Item);
  }
```

```js
// query.component.ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setItemMode(ItemMode.Item);
  }
```

```js
// service.ts
  getItemModeState(): Observable<ItemMode> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select((state) => state.siteState.itemMode),
      startWith(ItemMode.List)
    );
  }

  setItemMode(payload: ItemMode): void {
    this.store.dispatch(Actions.setItemMode({ payload: payload }));
  }
```

Body-component is the parent of Item- and Query-Component. Item and Query will update the itemMode state and Body updates some navigation. Everything works well instead of the error which prompts up.

To Analyze the error I tried to debug it but werent capable to figure it out myself. Would be have to get some support.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution(which will fix a problem and allow to not remember subscription, since `async` pipe handles subscription) might be to use `async` pipe instead of setting it after load

```js
// body.component.ts
...
public readonly itemMode$: Observable<ItemMode>;
...
constructor(...) {
  this.itemMode$ = this.service.getItemModeState().pipe(
    // this logic is needed if we use `itemMode$ | async` more than once and don't want to reload `itemMode` on every subscription, but want to reuse `itemMode` of first subscription without additional load
    // shareReplay({
    //   bufferSize: 1,
    //   refCount: true,
    // })
  );
}
```

```html
// body.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="itemMode$ | async as itemMode">
    <ng-container *ngIf="itemMode >= ItemMode.List"> <a> List</a> > </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This solution is cleaner, because

- It allows to move handling of subscription into `async` pipe and not store subscription in variable to dispose of it later(if you don't dispose of subscription, you have potential memory leak)
- It allows to use more performant `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`
- It eases reacting to changes of `itemMode` in code

Comment: Thanks @Ivan for your quick response.
The itemMode should change several times. Everytime when there is switch between the Item- and Query-Component.

I updated the suggested code. Sadly with the usage of itemMode$ it complains `Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)`.

Comment: @Jason  Oh, right, forgot that newer version of angular has stricter type checks, updating answer now

Comment: @Jason Added wrapper `<ng-container *ngIf="itemMode$ | async as itemMode">` to answer. We can also move this logic `itemMode >= ItemMode.List` to `.pipe(..., map(itemMode => itemMode !== null && itemMode >= ItemMode.List))` and rename `this.itemMode$` to `this.isItemModeListLike$`

Comment: With the wrapper, it functions, but it exhibits a slightly different behavior. It does not display the initial text when the page is loaded and still produces the error.

Comment: Your second approach appears to be effective and works well.


`// body.component.ts itemModeList$!: Observable<boolean>; ... this.itemModeList$ = this.service.getItemModeState().pipe( map((itemMode) => itemMode !== null && itemMode >= ItemMode.List)); ...`

`// body.component.html <ng-container *ngIf="itemModeList$ | async"> <a>List</a> > </ng-container>`. 

However, I have around six different scenarios to check, which is why it would be convenient if I could perform the comparison directly in the template

Comment: @Jason Is this approach ok for you(currrently answer has version with this approach)
```
// body.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="itemMode$ | async as itemMode">
    <ng-container *ngIf="itemMode >= ItemMode.List"> <a> List</a> > </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Jason Maybe the problem is in other component. Try using same approach(converting lately initialized variable to Observable) there

Comment: #1 Working in the template still triggers the error and produces an undesired behavior. #2 In the other components (query and item), I am not utilizing observables. Instead, I update the store (nrgx) when the page is loaded. I hope the provided StackBlitz link assists in clarifying the situation. The body-component is the only component that holds an observable for itemMode.